# need imagemagick log.xml format

Tags: xml, logging, configuration, imagemagick

can anyone point me to some documentation detailing the parameterisation of ImageMagick's log.xml file ?  everything i've been able to find so far, above and beyond the 1-paragraph description on the ImageMagick 'resources' page, is just a dump of the default file itself. i'm interested in learning the specifics related to the 'events', 'output', 'filename', etc. parameters.

thanks,
dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example `log.xml` is given in the source, and looks like this:

```
<!--
    The format of the log is defined by embedding special format characters:

    %c   client
    %d   domain
    %e   event
    %f   function
    %g   generation
    %i   thread id
    %l   line
    %m   module
    %n   log name
    %p   process id
    %r   real CPU time
    %t   wall clock time
    %u   user CPU time
    %v   version
    %%   percent sign
    \n   newline
    \r   carriage return
-->
<logmap>
    <log events="None"/>
    <log output="console"/>
    <log filename="Magick-%g.log"/>
    <log generations="3"/>
    <log limit="2000"/>
    <log format="%t %r %u %v %d %c[%p]: %m/%f/%l/%d\n  %e"/>
</logmap>
```

Logs will only be generated when issuing the [-debug](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#debug) options, and the events will need to match the `log.xml` value *(and they can be comma separated)*. Options for `events` are:

- None
- All
- Accelerate
- Annotate
- Blob
- Cache
- Coder
- Configure
- Deprecate
- Exception
- Locale
- Render
- Resource
- Security
- TemporaryFile
- Transform
- X11
- User

The `output` option maps handler of the buffer. You probably what `file` to write to a standard log file. Other options for `output` would be:

- Console
- Debug
- Event
- File
- None
- Stderr
- Stdout

Take a lot @ the source file `log.c` for more detail about `output` options. Other attributes like `filename`, `limit`, and `format` are pretty standard & behave like other logging APIs. I'd recommend keeping them set to default values.

**For example:**

If I'm only interested in logging memory `resources` against `real CPU time`. I can configure `log.xml` as

```xml
<logmap>
    <log events="Resource"/>
    <log output="File"/>
    <log filename="Magick-Resource-%p.log"/>
    <log generations="3"/>
    <log limit="2000"/>
    <log format="%u|%e" />
</logmap>
```

This will create a local log file identified by the process id, and record a pipe-delimited message. Running the command `convert -debug Resource rose: -negate rose.png` will generate a file entitled '**Magick-Resource-5937.log**', and would contain something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<log>
  <event>0.010u|Area: 25.8KB/25.8KB/4.295GB</event>
  <event>0.010u|Memory: 25.8KB/25.2KiB/2GiB</event>
  <event>0.020u|Memory: 210B/25.4KiB/2GiB</event>
  <event>0.020u|Memory: 210B/25.2KiB/2GiB</event>
  <event>0.020u|Memory: 25.8KB/0B/2GiB</event>
</log>
```

Comment: thank you !  this is exactly what i was looking for !  better, even. :)